# Ubuntu 22.04 - Installing old nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have an old computer with integrated graphics in the motherboard (geforce 7025/nforce 630). I managed to install ubuntu 22.04 without any mayor issues, but the graphical interface doesn't look quite right, sometimes it seems like it's glitching (wierd artifacts instead of animations on the desktop) and overall the performance isn't great.

I thought it might me a problem with the nouveau driver so I tried installing one form nvidia. I think the best one for me would be 304, but it isn't listed among the drivers available through console commands.

I tried adding the PPA GPU repository `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` but the 304 driver still wasn't showing.

I downloaded the .run file from nvidia's website and went through a long process in order to be able to excecute that file. I don't remember all the steps, but it involved logging in to tty2 (crtl + alt + F2), blacklisting nouveau with a file (I think it was lovated in /etc/modprobe.d), installing a couple of missing packages.
The last error message that I got was that

> The path to the 'modprobe' utility reported by '/proc/sys/kernel/modprobe', '/sbin/modprobe', differs from the path determined by the 'nvidia-installer', '/usr/sbin/modprobe'. Please verify that 'sbin/modprobe' works correctly and correct path in 'proc/sys/kernel/modprobe' if it does not.

I don't have a lot of experience in linux but it seems that it's trying to open a directory that doesn't exist or maybe it got relocated in newer versions of linux. In any case, I don't know what to try next, is there any way to fix that error and complete the installation?

Comment: It is not possible to install old drivers to a new system.

Comment: What do you mean by "new system"? New hardware or a new os? Because it's not new hardware. The CPU is an AMD fx-4100 and the motherboard is an Asrock n68 vs3 fx. Those are the core components, if it helps I can also list the rest of the hardware, but as I said, it's not "new" (besides the ssd, which is the more "modern" part of the pc).

Comment: I mean new kernel.